# how to access mac files from ubuntu flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, files, osx, virtual-machine, macintosh

So I'm running ubuntu from a thumb drive that's plugged into my Mac. I want to access some files from the Mac harddrive while I'm booted into ubuntu, but when I click on the MacOSX harddrive to locate the files, I get this error:

"Unable to access location. Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/MacOSX: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

I don't want to mess anything up with the Mac laptop in and of itself, I just want to get some files from the harddrive. Is there a way to do this that won't pose any possible future issues with the Mac?

Comment: second answer: https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write